# FFMpeg trim video based on frame numbers (have code but audio isn't trimming)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding

I'm trying to trim and re-encode my videos based on frame numbers. The following works great for my videos

```
-vf select="between(n\,$start_frame\,$end_frame),setpts=PTS-STARTPTS"
```

however this doesn't trim the audio since its `vf` filter.

Any ideas how I can trim the audio perfectly with my video?

P.S. Tried `-af aselect="..."` but didn't work

Comment: Use aselect with timestamps not frame counts.

Comment: I tried timestamps as in frame_number/fps but I am getting slight mismatch. My video is constant 29.97 fps. Any ideas how to accurately convert?

Comment: If you have constant framerate, why not just trim with  `-ss inpoint` and `-to length` ?

Comment: Audio framing is unrelated to video frames. Need file details for conversion purposes.

Comment: Because if I do 29890/29.97 i.e. 997.3306639, no matter how many decimals I use, ffmpeg goes +/- 1 frame in all my files.

Comment: You can't encode/output half frames, so what exactly are you expecting as output?